# Google Sheets API v4 - Insert Row Above (Not below)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Has anyone had any luck getting the insertDimension request to insert a row *above* existing data? My code below only inserts a row at the bottom and I can't find any documentation on how to say *where* I want to add the row... having a lot of problems with the new API...

```
function insertRow() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

        var options = {
            auth: auth,
            spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
            resource: {
                requests: [{
                    insertDimension: {
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 1769404692,
                            dimension: "ROWS",
                            startIndex: 1,
                            endIndex: 2
                        },
                        inheritBefore: true
                    }
                }],
            }
        }

        sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(options, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This code works in that it does insert a row, just not where I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. I've come to two solutions, maybe it fits on yours.

The first one is to select a row to sort the range, append the new value and sort again to normalize the order. I'm using the `sortRange`

The second one is to use the [`MoveDimensionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#movedimensionrequest), [`InsertDimensionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest).

I suggest to look into [spreadsheet collection](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets), there you can manipulate most of the aspects of your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I found this question searching for a similar problem.

Just set your startIndex one row up if you want it above a certain row. In your case if you want it inserted above row 1, set `startIndex: 0`. But if you do, you must also set the `inheritBefore: false` because there is no row before index 0 to inherit from.